# Serial.println for pointers to the byte datatype behaves unexpectedly

Tags: arduino-uno

```
byte subkeys[16][48/8];

for (size_t address = 0; address < 16*6; address++)
    Serial.println( (byte) *(subkeys + address) );
```

Why won't the compiler handle this? It tells me

> cast from 'byte* {aka unsigned char*}' to 'byte {aka unsigned char}' loses precision [-fpermissive]

If I omit the `(byte)` part, it tells me

> call of overloaded 'println(byte [6])' is ambiguous

I have no idea what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `byte` is to small to store a pointer value. Instead to casting to
byte, you should cast to `uintptr_t`, which is guaranteed to be large
enough. On an AVR-based device like the Uno, this is the same as
`uint16_t` or `unsigned int`, but `uintptr_t` is more general.

**Edit**: From your comment it would seem you want to print the contents
of the array instead of the addresses of the rows. The obvious way is to
loop with two indices:

```cpp
for (size_t i = 0; i < 16; i++) for (size_t j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    Serial.println(subkeys[i][j]);
```

If you really want to use `subkeys` as a 1D array, then cast it to a
`byte *`, which is the type a 1D array would naturally decay to:

```cpp
for (size_t address = 0; address < 16*6; address++)
    Serial.println(((byte *) subkeys)[address]);
```

Comment: But *(subkeys + address) is not a pointer. It is a value in subkeys array. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, `subkeys` is an array of arrays of bytes, then `*subkeys` (as well as `subkeys[address]`, which is a nicer syntax for `*(subkeys + address)`) is an array of 6 bytes. In most cases, arrays decay to pointers when you use them. You should probably start by telling us what you want to achieve.